# Linked List creating a List

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This is a block of code from my simple Linked List program.

```
void insertFirst(double dd){
        Link* pNewLink = new Link(dd);

        if (isEmpty())
            pLast = pNewLink;

        pNewLink->pNext = pFirst;
        pFirst = pNewLink;

    }
```

My doubt is how does `Link* pNewLink = new Link(dd);` works ? I know pNewLink is a pointer to the new Link Object. But I am not getting while creating a Linked List how does multiple links are created and how are they connected?

Comment: A video tutorial or a class lecture should be helpful

Comment: There are multiple resources that explain how linked lists work, easily to be found using the search engine of your choice. Have you read one or more of them? This a very, very basic topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new Link(dd) statement is creating a new linked list node rather than a new list. So that, using the pFirst pointer, you replace the new node as the first node by setting its next pointer to the pFirst. After that, you overwrite the content of pFirst which was declared inside the linked list class (if it's a class).

Answer (score -1):

Here is java Implementation of LinkedList

```
public class SingLyLinkedList 
{
Node head = null;

static class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int x) {
        data = x;

    }

}

public static SingLyLinkedList insert(SingLyLinkedList list, int data) {
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    temp.next = null;

    if (list.head == null) {
        list.head = temp;

    } else {

        Node last = list.head;
        while (last.next != null) {
            last = last.next;

        }
        last.next = temp;

    }

    return list;

}

public static void printList(SingLyLinkedList list) {

    Node currNode = list.head;
    while (currNode != null) {
        System.out.print(currNode.data + "  ");
        currNode = currNode.next;

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SingLyLinkedList ll = new SingLyLinkedList();
    ll.insert(ll, 10);
    ll.insert(ll, 20);
    ll.insert(ll, 30);
    ll.insert(ll, 40);
    printList(ll);

}}
```

Comment: This is in Java, and OP was asking about a specific issue with pointers in C++. Java doesn't even have pointers, so I fail to see how your answer could be useful to answering the question.